# MySQL: Create table from select with engine different from source table

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I would like to copy an existing table data to a new table with a different engine:

```
CREATE TABLE `t_backup` (SELECT * FROM `t`) ENGINE=MyIsam;
```

But it prompts syntax error. I know I can write the following statements as a workaround:

```
CREATE TABLE `t_backup` (SELECT * FROM `t1`);
ALTER TABLE `t_backup` ENGINE = MyIsam;
```

I am just wondering if there's a statment that can copy an existing table data to a new table with a different engine, in just one SQL statement (MySQL or MariaDB variant statements are also okay). Thanks!

Comment: This first example [on this page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-select.html) answers your question. By the way, MyISAM is obsolete.

Comment: @O.Jones Thanks, that's what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use next syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE t_backup ENGINE=MyIsam AS SELECT * FROM t;
```

[MariaDB fiddle](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=&sqlses=a758f80536b6959d2fee35df3d2f7a69&php_version=null&sql_version=mariadb)